# How to pass a callback data to second function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `tcp-ping` to ping a server, and then I want to make a callback function that will POST the data to my database via the `request` library. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the callback to send data to the second function.

The problem is that there is no error, but the form data for Min, Max, and Avg are not being recorded in mongodb. I don't know how to retrieve the data, or know if the data is even being sent.

```
tcpp.ping({ address: 'www.google.com' }, function(err, data) {

    postPingData(function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log(500, { error: 'something blew up' });
      } else {
        console.log(data); // I understand this is incorrect, but I don't know how else I'm supposed to send data. 
      }
    });

    console.log(data);
});

var postPingData = function(callback){
    console.log(callback);
    request.post({
      headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      url:     'http://localhost:8080/api/pingdata',
      form:    {
                    ping_id: "5852fd1976ba7111cd9b78aa",
                    min: callback.min,
                    max: callback.max,
                    avg: callback.avg
                }
    }, function(error, response, body){

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      status = "succeeded";
      callback(null, {status : status});
    } else {
      callback(error);
    }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially it seems you would want to inject the data argument passed to the callback to tcpp.ping - which will be the result of the ping operation if successful - to your postPingData function:

```
tcpp.ping({ address: 'www.google.com' }, function(err, data) {

    postPingData(data, function(err, data){

    ...

var postPingData = function(data, callback){

    ...

    form: {
             ping_id: "5852fd1976ba7111cd9b78aa",
             min: data.min,
             max: data.max,
             avg: data.avg
          }
```